# Can someone tell me why my laptop's showing such high temps? I'm unable to run most of the things i could run before

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, cp, cpu-temperature

[screenshot of task manager sorted by cu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USQ3x.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtS4t.jpg video of ask manager processes

my temperatures reach upto a 100 degree celsius sometimes.Most of the time they're at 80 or 70 with only chrome and zoom open. It's not a malware problem since i've hard reset it twice already.
the temperatures keep changing right now from 70 to 99 and in between any temp randomly i have no idea why.

i have an acer E5 573 G bought in november 2015 and replaced the whole motherboard in 2018 because of low performance/ heating issues just like now i guess.

specs :
i5 5200 u 4gb graphics
geforce 920m 2gb vram ddr4
8gb ddr3l ram

Comment: You need a hardware professional. It can even be a bad temp sensor, so is not real (especially if it's going up and down randomly, as you say).

Comment: Have you cleaned your fans recently? A can of compressed reduced my max temperature by 25-30 C

Comment: i dont think its a bad temp sensor since it really does become very hot when i touch it.mi had the fans cleaned back in february as far as i can remember. the warranty's over by now so im thinking i should open it by myself and try cleaning it. Maybe its a thermal paste issue irdk.

Answer (score 0):

You say it's not malware, but clearly **something** is running on your system chewing up CPU resources.  This is indicated by the high clock speed and CPU utilisation figure you have shown.

Pull up a task manager and see what is eating the CPU.  Then kill it.

Its entirely possible the problem is websites you are browsing - maybe a corrupt cache?

Comment: i have no idea what's taking up my cpu but i can provide screenshots of the task managers. would you be as kind as to look into them?

Comment: hello , i've added 6 screenshots of my gask manager , please let me know what's wrong

Comment: Those screenshots are a bit bizare.  Can you click on the CPU field to sort by CPU usage?  Your 25% CPU is not consistent with what is visible on the CPU components visible on-screen.   (I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure if you can sort it this way, but I imagine you can).

Comment: i've addded the screenshot of the task manager sorted by cpu usage. please check.